# Hitting api for image on click of 'a' tag

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, api

So basically I am hitting the api to get only a specific breed image at the moment.. 
You get something like this when you hit the api for the image in the json

url: "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/dLrzJVXo1.jpg"

and I want to display that image, I'm just not sure how to go about having that specific breed on click show that cats image.

Api being used is : https://docs.thecatapi.com/

I also really only want one breed, and image to show on the page at one time so that way you can say click to go to the next image or back to the last image, and maybe add a button to click and show all breeds, and you can click to view the list of breed names.

Here is currently what my code looks like, and yes I want to keep the class part of the requirement, it just displays the items in a list but for some reason its one big A tag LI, they aren't separated.

Javascript :

```
    // const catPictures = document.getElementById("catBreeds");


class CatBreed {
    constructor(breed) {
        this.breeds = [];
    }
    static async fetchCat(url) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log('Here is that cat info you asked for: ', data)
            data.map(cat => console.log('here is an individual cat: ', cat))
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
    static async onLoad(url) {
        const catData = await this.fetchCat(url);
        const catContainer = document.getElementById("catList");
        const catLinks = catData.map((cat) => {
            const link = document.createElement('li');
            link.innerHTML = cat.name
            console.log(link)
            return catContainer.appendChild(link);
        });
    }

    static async fetchCatImage(url) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const catImage = await response.json();
            console.log('test', catImage)
            return catImage;
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
};

CatBreed.onLoad('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds')
CatBreed.fetchCatImage('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=tvan')

// catPictures.addEventListener('click', async () => {
//     const catData = await CatBreed.fetchCat('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds');
//     const catContainer = document.getElementById("catList");
//     const catLinks = catData.map((cat) => {
//         const link = document.createElement('li');
//         link.innerHTML = cat.link
//         console.log(link)
//         return catContainer.appendChild(link);
//     });
// });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="catContainer">
        <h1>Cat Api</h1>
        <p>Click to view some pictures of that specific breed</p>
        <ul class="catList">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS file:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    }

    class CatBreed {
        constructor(breed) {
            this.breeds = [];
        }
        static async fetchCat(url) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Here is that cat info you asked for: ', data)
                data.map(cat => console.log('here is an individual cat: ', cat))
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                return error;
            }
        }
        static onLoad(url) {
            const catData = this.fetchCat(url);
            const catContainer = document.getElementById("catBreeds");
            const catLinks = catData.map((cat) => {
                const link = document.createElement('li');
                link.innerHTML = cat.name
                console.log(link)
                return catContainer.appendChild(link);
            });
        }

        static async fetchCatImage(url) {
            const catImg = await this.fetchCat(url);
            const catImgContainer = document.getElementById("catImg");
            const catImgLink = catImg.map((cat) => {
                catImgContainer.src = cat.url;
            });
        }
    };

    CatBreed.fetchCatImage('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=tvan')

    var btnSearch = document.getElementById("btnShowAll");
    btnSearch.onclick = function () {
        CatBreed.onLoad('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds')
    }
```

CSS:

```
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

img {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="catContainer">
        <h1>Cat Api</h1>
        <p>Click to view some pictures of that specific breed</p>
        <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="width: 200px; margin-left: 0px">
            <img class="mySlides" id="catImg" style="width:100%">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="catList">
            <li id="catListing">
                <a href="" id="catBreeds"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="btnShowAll">Show All</button>
```

Sry but I can get the data of this link https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds. Some protected on my local machine.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help, I now need the image, which I am having trouble getting from the function.